# Android device can't scan beacon

Tags: android, beacon

I'm working on a simple beacon proximity app using AltBeacon library from here https://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/samples.html.

I am experimenting with the sample code provided on the above website, however, each time I run the app it only goes to `addRangingNotifier()` method. If it detected the beacon it would go log the beacon size.

```
private Region defaultRegion = null;
defaultRegion = new Region("BeaconIdentifier", Identifier.fromUuid(java.util.UUID.fromString(UUID)), null, null);
beaconManager = BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(this);
beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser().setBeaconLayout("m:2-3=0215,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24"));
beaconManager.bind(this);

@Override
public void onBeaconServiceConnect() {
   beaconManager.addRangeNotifier(new RangeNotifier() {
      @Override
      public void didRangeBeaconsInRegion(Collection<Beacon> beacons, Region region) {
         if (beacons.size() > 0) {
            Log.d("MainInfo","Beacon List Size " + beacons.size());
         }else{
            Log.d("MainInfo","Beacon Empty");
         }
      }
   });
   try {
      beaconManager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(defaultRegion);
   } catch (RemoteException e) {}
}
```

I can receive the beacon size around of me.
**I test the two device(A : Samsung galaxy J510-Marshmellow/B: Samsung galaxy J7-Nougat), B scan the beacon and print Beacon List Size, but, A can't scan the beacon and print Beacon Empty**.

So I test same Marshmellow device, but I can't find it.

Are there any codes that should be added depending on the operating system?

Comment: Maybe worth checking that if the location permission is granted to the app on the phone?

Comment: @RickyMo Of course that

Comment: Did this solve the problem?

Comment: @davidgyoung yes. when I change dependencies {
     implementation 'org.altbeacon:android-beacon-library:2+'
   } to AAR file (in project structure and import aar file), it show the scan result. So now I can scan. Thank you for your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most likely thing wrong is that the UUID specified does not match your beacon.  Try replacing this code:

```
  Identifier.fromUuid(java.util.UUID.fromString(UUID))
```

With

```
  null
```

To match all beacons.  If this fixes it, replace the UUID with the one you are out of the detected beacon.

Comment: Ok I'll test it. but I suggest why B device can scan it,  but A device can't scan it. If UUID is wrong, I guess B device also can't scan it.

Comment: defaultRegion = new Region("BeaconIdentifier", null, null, null); but still can't scan..

Comment: I test another C device (API 24, Marshmellow, galaxy J7 2016), but still can't